# Find pre-map element in stream corresponding to post-map minimum

Tags: java, reduce

I often find myself doing something like this:

```
list.stream().min(new Comparator<>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(E a, E b) {
        return Double.compare(f(a),f(b));
    }
})
```

where `f` is a computation intensive function. This requires twice as many evaluations of `f` as are actually necessary. I'd prefer to

```
list.stream().mapToDouble(f).min()
```

but then I don't know how to get the original element that this minimum corresponds to.

One ugly way around this is

```
class WithF<E>{
    private final E e;
    private final double fe;
    WithF(E e, double fe){
        this.e = e;
        this.fe = fe;
    }
    public E getE(){
        return e;
    }
    public double getFE(){
        return fe;
    }
}
```

and then

```
list.stream().map(e -> new WithF<>(e,f(e))).min(Comparator.comparingDouble(WithF::getFE))
```

Is there a better, idiomatic way of doing this thing with the stream API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This transformation is often called the [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

I'd actually generalize `WithF` with a few extra bits, and rename it to make the pipe neater.

```
class SchwartzianKV<E, SORTKEY implements Comparable<SORTKEY> > 
      implements Comparable<SchwartzianKV<E, SORTKEY>> {

    public final E e;
    public final SORTKEY sortkey;

    SchwartzianKV(E e, SORTKEY sortkey){
        this.e = e;
        this.sortkey = sortkey;
    }

    public static <E, SORTKEY implements Comparable<SORTKEY>> 
    Function<E, SchwartzianKV<E, SORTKEY>> transformer( Function<E, SORTKEY> fn ) {
       return new Function<E, SchwartzianKV<E,SORTKEY>>() {
           @Override SchwartzianKV<E,SORTKEY> apply(E e) {
               return new SchwartzianKV<>(e, fn.apply(e));
           } 
       }
    }

    public int compare(With<E> other) {
       return sortkey.compare(other.sortkey);
    }
}
```

Now you can write the stream as

```
 Optional<E> minValue = list.stream()
                            .map( SchwartianKV.transformer( e -> f(e) ) )
                            .min()
                            .map( kv -> kv.e )
```

Which is pretty concise.

Comment: This is probably the "right" way, but to me it feels like killing an ant with a sledgehammer. +1 for the reference and for implementing `Comparable` - makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @tennenrishin I agree, except this is more reusable than the other options. So if you do it more than once I'd use this, otherwise the other options may be better suited.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Optional<E> minE = list.stream()
    .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(e, f(e))
    .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
```

That essentially creates a map entry for each of the list items to the double value then finds the `min` entry using the values and finally gets the matching key.

Note that it returns an `Optional` to allow for the situation in which there are no items in the list in which case you will get an `empty`. Alternatively you could add a `orElse` call to the end to return another `E` if the list is empty.

It is a slightly unusual use of Map.Entry (i.e. not putting it in a map). There are libraries with a `Pair` class which could do the same job or you could create your own.

Comment: Then why not just replace `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), E::f).entrySet().stream()` with `.map(e -> new SimpleEntry(e,f(e)))` ?

Comment: @tennenrishin I can't see a `SimpleEntry` class in the Java 8 API. Can you point me to a reference? Would certainly be simpler way to go (or use a `Pair` from one of the standard libraries).

Comment: Its a little ugly that this creates a complete intermediate collection.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson yes I agree. It'd be nice if the Java library had an easy way of creating a simple pair as that's all that's required here. I tried a solution that created a List of two items for each entry but that was even uglier.

Comment: @sprinter `import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;`

Answer (score 1):

While waiting I'll post what I'm currently considering:

```
List<Double> fs = list.stream()
    .map(e -> f(e))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
int i = IntStream.range(0,fs.size()).boxed()
    .min(java.util.Comparator.comparingDouble(fs::get))
    .get();
list.get(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.stream()
    .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e,f(e)))
    .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
```

basically uses `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<E,Double>` in place of `WithF<E>` from the question. Not the intended usage of `Map.Entry` so not ideal.